# Python file I/O significantly slower than OpenCV imread

Tags: python, opencv, io

I have an image dataset where the byte stream for several JPEG images is merged into a single binary file. The byte offsets and number of bytes occupied by each image are known, so I'm using the following code snippet to read it:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def get_image(binary_file_path, byte_offset, buffer_size):
    with open(binary_file_path, 'rb') as ifile:
        ifile.seek(byte_offset)
        image_buffer = np.asarray(bytearray(ifile.read(buffer_size)), np.uint8)  # TOO SLOW
        return cv2.imdecode(image_buffer, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
```

On my machine, the line marked with the "TOO SLOW" comment takes around 50ms to execute. By contrast, if I use `cv2.imread` to parse a regular JPEG image file, it hardly takes 10ms.

Worth noting: In the code snippet above, it's taking 50ms **just to read the bytes**, whereas `cv2.imread` is able to read the file and decode the JPEG format all in 10ms.

I would really like to know the reason behind this large discrepancy.

P.S. The times mentioned above were obtained when running the code from within a multiprocessing pool, in case that is relevant.

Comment: Why do you read the bytes, convert them to a bytearray and convert that to an np array - instead of just reading the bytes?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi missed that piece, thanks for clarifying

Comment: @MisterMiyagi because `cv2.imdecode` expects an object of type `cv2.UMat`. It throws an error if you directly feed it the output from `ifile.read()`

Comment: Alright, let me rephrase that - why are you surprised that working on the entire content four times is slower than streaming it once? How large is your data, how large are your caches, are you CPU or IO bound?

Comment: How is it 4 times? I tried replacing that line with `image_buffer = np.frombuffer(ifile.read(buffer_size), np.uint8)` or `image_buffer = np.fromstring(ifile.read(buffer_size), np.uint8)` and the difference is negligible. With the former, I'm quite certain that no copies of the data are being made, it's just a simple reinterpretation of an existing data structure.
And right now I'm entirely IO bound, followed by GPU bound. The CPU is almost completely idle.